# Notifications not stacking

Tags: android, notifications, localnotification

I am trying to create stacked local notifications when user opens an activity. I am not able to see them stacked. All of them appears separately. I have referred to many other stack overflow questions but none worked. Below is my code :

```
public class NotificationGroupActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createNotifications();
}

private void createNotifications() {

    final  String GROUP_KEY_EMAILS = "group_key_emails";
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    for(int i = 0; i<10;i++) {

// Build the notification, setting the group appropriately
        Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New mail from " + i)
                .setContentText("SUBJECT " + i)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .build();
// Issue the notification
        notificationManager.notify(i + 10, notif);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using different IDs (the first parameter of the `.notify(int, Notification)` method) for each of the notifications your'e issuing.

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html#Updating) says:

> To update this notification once you've issued it, update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same ID you used previously.

So you must replace

```
notificationManager.notify(i + 10, notif);
```

With:

```
notificationManager.notify(0 /* Or any constant*/, notif);
```

Consider that this will *replace* the old notification, if you want to achieve something like what Whatsapp or Inbox do you must provide your own custom layout for stacked notifications